# bootstrap dropdown button trigger from other button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to trigger the dropdown button from another button and can't seem to get it to work.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cv19ou74/)

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnFilter">Action</button>
<button type="button" id="btntest" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" style="display:none;">Action <span class="caret"></span>
</button>

<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Action</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
  </li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    $('#btnFilter').on('click', function(){
       $("#btntest").trigger('click');
    });
});
```

Comment: in my case it needs to be display none :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `stopPropagation` to your button click.

http://jsfiddle.net/cv19ou74/1/